# Spring Security with multiple login pages only takes order 1

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, controller

I have a Spring Boot application where login page will be at index(nav) and also at login page. I did the order annotation configuration however it only works as expected the order 1 (tested by switching order and the 1 is only working ok) For the order 2 error: Request method 'POST' not supported, any idea?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl")
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class WebSecurityConfig1 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.requestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**"))
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/registration", "/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/loginIndex")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .failureUrl("/loginIndex?error")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/loginIndex")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll();
        }
    }
    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class WebSecurityConfig2 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.requestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**"))
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/registration","/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return authenticationManager();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue in your config**

1. `WebSecurityConfig1` and `WebSecurityConfig2` both configured to match every urls. .ie `new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**")`
2. It means `@Order(1)` will always satisfy all requests.

**Solution**

So first you need to decide for which urls you want the user redirected to first login page and for which urls you want the user redirected to second login page.

For example, you can say urls staring with `/user` goes to `loginPage("/loginIndex")` and everything else goes to `loginPage("/login")`. You can achieve it by replacing `new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**")` with (`new AntPathRequestMatcher("/user*")`) in WebSecurityConfig1